# get the element i hoverd on in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an html page with multiple div's tables spans ect...
what I want to do basically is creating a color picker when the mouse hover on an element I want to read it's color using `.css("color")` and return it's value
How can I know what is the element i hovered on and get it's ID so i can read the css.
I know I should use the `.hover()` function but so i can call it it should be like this -->`$("#element").hover()` where `element` is the html element I am currently hover on.but this is not the case here because i don't know what is the current element I am hovering on .
Any help appreciate it

```
$(window).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
 var element = e.target;

});
```

is this how i should read the element ?

Comment: post your trying or fiddle link

Comment: "div's tables spans ect" What is your html structure, which are the elements to which you need to add hover event handler - do they have a common selector..? please update the question with proper info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use JQuery's all selector with hover: `$('*').hover(function(){ ... },function () {});` and you'll need to convert inline elements to inline-block and then back again to read the color. The second empty function in hover makes sure hover only fires once per mouseover.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P24QC/)**

Answer (score 3):

If you add `element_to_hover` class to the required elements, you can use `$(this)`

```
$('.element_to_hover').hover(function() {
    alert($(this).css('color'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

**html**

```
<div style="background:red;width:50px;height:50px;"></div>
<div style="background:green;width:50px;height:50px;"></div>
<div style="background:blue;width:50px;height:50px;"></div>
<div style="background:yellow;width:50px;height:50px;"></div>
```

**js**

```
$("div").on("mouseenter",function(){
    console.log($(this).css("background"));
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gp4W/2/)